# how do i compare the special string in query

Tags: kdb

I would like to query and there is special character in the table

For example:

```
tab:([]a:("ab*cd*ef";"3rr3f";"fewfa");b:1 2 3)
```

I tried this

```
select from tab where a like "ab*cd*ef"
```

This doesnt work.
I am using this in a function so it will extract the exact word to a variable

```
 variable:"ab*cd*ef"
```

and I use this variable to match with another table. wondering how this should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` is a wildcard for matching any sequence of characters. Unfortunately kdb doesn't support complicated regex out of the box but you can escape `*` in this case with the notation for lists of alternatives.

```
q)select from tab where a like "ab[*]cd[*]ef"
a          b
------------
"ab*cd*ef" 1
```

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/regex/

Comment: yes, in kdb, tho strange, `[]` are the escapes for most special characters.